# How to ensure stability on all device that can use the Android TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, samsung-mobile, gyroscope

I am using TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR as sensor in Android project. However, on some devices (Example S22 Ultra), I saw a difference in rotation angles from the sensor. For example, while most devices see a difference of 30 degrees from point A to point B, I see it as more than 30 degrees in the s22 ultra, as in the example.

```
 sensorManager?.registerListener(
            this,
            sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME
        )
```

Is there any way I can increase the calibration or accuracy rate in SensorManager to avoid this type of problem? Thanks